# Exception while running docker compose for rabbitmq

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq, zipkin

```
2021-02-10 16:00:04.261 INFO 1 --- [ main] c.i.m.n.NamingServerApplication : Started NamingServerApplication in 20.797 seconds (JVM running for 21.293) naming-server_1
2021-02-10 16:00:04.305 INFO 1 --- [ Thread-10] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server zipkin-server_1
2021-02-10 16:00:05.027 WARN [/] 1 --- [ main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'armeriaServer' defined in com.linecorp.armeria.spring.ArmeriaAutoConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'armeriaServer' parameter 5;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverConfigurator' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinHttpConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverConfigurator' parameter 2;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.health.ZipkinHealthController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitMq' defined in zipkin2.server.internal.rabbitmq.ZipkinRabbitMQCollectorConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;
    nested exception is java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: rabbitmq: Try again zipkin-server_1
```

```yaml
rabbitmq:
  image : rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
  mem_limit: 300m
  ports: 
    - "5672:5672"
    - "15672:15672"
  environment:
    RABBIT_URI : amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672

zipkin-server:
  image : openzipkin/zipkin:2.23
  mem_limit: 300m
  ports: 
  - "9411:9411"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had faced similar issue and it was fixed by adding `restart: always` key-value for `zipkin-server`. You can specify the `RABBIT_URI` for `zipkin-server`, but `rabbitmq` might not require it to be specified. And if you are planning to save the traces in mq in case zipkin is down, adding this dependency to `zipkin-server` can help:

```
depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
```

So the .yaml snippet will look like:

```
rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.5.3-management
    mem_limit: 300m
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

zipkin-server:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:2.23
    mem_limit: 300m
    ports:
      - "9411:9411"
    environment:
      RABBIT_URI: amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little easier if you write down what you are trying to achieve and properly format the error and the yaml. If you do it you will have a better chance to spot this in the last line:

`java.io.UncheckedIOException: Unable to establish connection to RabbitMQ server: rabbitmq: Try again zipkin-server_1`

This means that the application is not able to connect to the host, try to update the host and use `localhost` if you are outside of the docker network i.e.: on the host and use the `container_name` if you are inside. I would also suggest defining the `container_name`, here is an example for [zipkin](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/local-services/blob/main/zipkin/docker-compose.yml) and here is one for [rabbit](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/local-services/blob/main/rabbit/docker-compose.yml)

Btw, I'm not sure what is the intention with `RABBIT_URI` inside of the `rabbitmq` service in your docker-compose.